# How to find all possible CSS Styles and Attributes of an Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

There are some ways to get all CSS styles of a DOM Element that are set with style or class Attribute. This works great, but if the class is not set to this it's not possible to find the classes that could be set to this element.

Now I'm looking for a way to get all CSS Classes and Styles that could be possible set to this DOM Element. I've tried something with RegExp but it's not perfect because I'm not sure how to search the document Style Node and compare it with the DOM Node. How is that possible?

Example what i need:

```
<div class="set">
  <p class="anotherclass">some text</p>
  <p class="otherClass">some text</p>
</div>
```

the css:

```
div.set { /* some css */ }
div.notSet { /* you could find me but not want to set me */ }
.autoSet_findMeToSet { /* set me to all tags with jquery */ }
div.autoSet_setMeNow { /* set me to the div tag with jquery */ }
div > p:first-child.autoSet_yeah { /* set me to the first p tag with jquery */
/* and so on */
```

As you can see I want to set with jQuery all css classes with special names. With regexp I could find the class names but I don't know how to check to which dom element (html tag) it needs to be set...

thanks for help at all!

Comment: Are you trying to get all inherit CSS rules for an element?

Comment: yes i think :)
i want to find all css rules (in <link> and <style> and style="..." etc.) that possibly could be set or used for a given element named by special expression (autoSet_... or something). but not even currently set for that given element.

Comment: The question is too vague. What are “CSS styles and attributes”? Do you mean CSS properties, or something else? What are “CSS classes”? Do you actually mean HTML classes? (CSS has no classes, just class selectors.) What have you tried to do in jQuery or otherwise in JavaScript?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to make any kind of sense, *any* class could be applied to *any* element. I don't think, as the question is written (and I may be misunderstanding your intent, of course), that there's any clear answer to be given. Can you give illustrative input/output?

Comment: Sorry that im not good to describe in englisch :)
Please take a look at the CSS Example above. I want to find all HTML Classes in the CSS File which starts with ".autoSet_...." for a chosen HTML Tag (like P). Like i'm saying "$('body > p').getPossibleCSS() -> will return me .autoSet_findMeToSet ... $('body div > p:first-child').getPossibleCSS() will retun me .autoSet_findMeToSet and also .autoSet_yeah from div > p:first-child.autoSet_yeah

so the p tag must not have the class attribute set in the DOM but i need to find the classes set in the css that maybe could be set to this (.autoSet_...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the found elements are inside of other elements using jQuery $.contains()

More info here how to do this here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

So for your example to find if some found classes are inside set you can do:

```
$.each(foundElement, function(index, domElement){
    if($.contains(domElement, $('.set'))) {
        // domElement is inside the container with 'set' class
    } else {
        // domElement is not inside the container with 'set' class
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right:

```
$(".class *")
```

selects all the elements inside an element with the class `class`

```
$(".class").find(element).length === 0
```

checks if element is inside an element with class `class`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but thats not the solution i think. because i don't know the name of some class. i just know some element and i need to know which classes and styles could be set for this element (but not even currently are set)